# Django - Celery: @transaction and @task don't stack

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I want to run a Django - Celery task with manual transaction management, but it seems that the annotations do not stack.

e.g.

```
def ping():
    print 'ping'
    pong.delay('arg')

@task(ignore_result=True)
@transaction.commit_manually()
def pong(arg):
    print 'pong: %s' % arg
    transaction.rollback()
```

results in

```
TypeError: pong() got an unexpected keyword argument 'task_name'
```

while the reverse annotation order results in

```
---> 22     pong.delay('arg')

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'delay'
```

It makes sense, but I'm having trouble finding a nice workaround.  The Django docs don't mention alternatives to the annotation, and I don't want to make a class for each celery Task when I don't need one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Previously Celery had some magic where a set of default keyword arguments
were passed to the task if it accepted them.

Since version 2.2 you can disable this behaviour, but the easiest is to
import the `task` decorator from `celery.task` instead of `celery.decorators`:

```
from celery.task import task

@task
@transaction.commit_manually
def t():
    pass
```

The `decorators` module is deprecated and will be completely removed in 3.0,
and the same for the "magic keyword arguments"

Note:
For custom Task classes you should set the `accept_magic_kwargs` attribute to False:

```
class MyTask(Task):
    accept_magic_kwargs = False
```

Note2: Make sure your custom decorators preserves the name of the function using `functools.wraps`, otherwise the task will end up with the wrong name.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for!  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The task decorator generates a `class x(Task)` from your function with the `run` method as your target. Suggest you define the class and decorate the method.

Untested e.g.:

```
class pong(Task):
  ignore_result = True

  @transaction.commit_manually()
  def run(self,arg,**kwargs):
    print 'pong: %s' % arg
    transaction.rollback()
```

Comment: Was hoping to find a non-class way to do it, but I guess this is the best alternative.  Thanks!